# Watson Discovery News - filter query to show a maximum of 1 result per domain

Tags: watson, watson-discovery

Lets say I run a query for the company Dell. Something like

```
{WATSON_URL}/query?
version=2016-1107&
query=entities.text%3ADell%2Centities.type%3ACompany%2Clanguage%3Aenglish&
count=&
offset=&
aggregation=&
filter=blekko.hostrank%3E200&
return=blekko.clean_title%2Centities.text%2Centities.type%2Cblekko.basedomain%2Cblekko.hostrank
```

All but 1 of the results is from the same publisher (Yahoo). Is there a way to Filter the results so that only a single result can come from a given publisher?

I can use an aggregation and still get an article with the 'top_hits' command

```
term(blekko.basedomain).top_hits(1)
```

This aggregation gives me roughly what I want but, in this case, I can't filter what fields I get back as I would be able to do if I could get this in the 'results' section.